# BigInteger loops and logic not working as planned

Tags: java, math, biginteger

so I'm trying to make some code where it basically factors really big numbers. I've tried to translate the code that worked using longs into BigIntegers but the result just returns a lot of 2s and 0s. Here it is.

```
package primes;
import java.math.BigInteger;
public class Primes {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigInteger y = new BigInteger("0");
        BigInteger count= new BigInteger("2");
        BigInteger input = new BigInteger("12321");
        BigInteger one = new BigInteger("1");

        while(input.compareTo(input)!=1) {
            y=input.mod(count);
            System.out.println(y);

            if(y.compareTo(y)==0) {
                input=input.divide(count);
                System.out.println(count);
            } else if(y.compareTo(y)!=0) {
                count.add(one);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alright, I see the problem with the count.add(one); but I am still unsure as to how the compareTo function works. Just for clarifciation with what each of these loops are supposed to do, I'm just going to paste the code of the functioning script that works with longs.

```
package longprimes;
public class LongPrimes {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long input = 121L;
    long count = 2;
    long y;
    while (input!=1){
        y = input%count;
        if(y==0){
            input = input/count;
            System.out.println(count);
        }
        else if(y!=0){
            count++;
        }
    }
}

}
```

Seemingly what is happening when I updated the BigInteger code a little bit is that it would factor it but it wouldn't divide input so that it would just keep finding the remainder but in the case that it was 0, it didn't actually divide input to end the loop.

Comment: Note that `new BigInteger("0")` can be replaced with `BigInteger.ZERO`; similarly you have `BigInteger.ONE`.

Comment: `if(y.compareTo(y)==0)` <-- eh? This will always be true! I gather this is not what you intended...

Comment: Also, `input.compareTo(input)!=1` will always be false. Even if you compared different values `a` and `b`, the `Comparable` interface only stipulates that 0 is returned when both values are considered similar with regards to their natural ordering, a positive integer if the first is greater than the second and a negative value otherwise. You have a _lot_ of flaws in your program.

Comment: " it just takes the remainder of the starting number 2 and the input and if it's zero, it divides the input and outputs 2 as a factor." <-- and what if the remainder is NOT zero (given your description it can only be 1 if it's not 0)?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a homework assignment, so I'll just point out a few things:

`input.compareTo(input)!=1` is probably not what you intended. Ideally, you want to finish that while loop when `input` is one. But `compareTo` will return -1, 0 or  1 if the number on the left is less, equal to, or greater than the other number. Consider what this condition actually returns.

`y.compareTo(y)==0` is kind of the same thing. You're comparing a number `y` with itself. Ideally, you want to compare with zero.

`count.add(one)` is not really doing anything. Consider what happens when you simply do

```
1 + 2;
```

you're computing the result of adding `one` to `count` but you're also ignoring the result. You might want to save that result somewhere.